# How do I evaluate the integral $\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+2}dx$?

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble with this problem. I can't see anywhere I can do $u$-substitution or anything.

$$\int\frac 1 {x^2+2}\,dx$$

Comment: Have you learned about trigonometric substitution?

Comment: Hint: substitute $x=\sqrt{2}\tan(\theta)$.

Comment: One does not "solve" and integral, one "evaluates" an integral.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int \frac 1{x^2 + 2}\,dx = \frac 12 \int \frac 1{ \left(\frac x{\sqrt 2}\right)^2 + 1}\,dx$$

A substitution of $\frac x{\sqrt 2} = u$ will convert this to a standard form where you can either make a tangent substitution ($u = \tan \theta$) or (if permitted) simply apply a standard result (often found in a table of standard integrals).

Answer (score 1):

It has the basic form of $\arctan(x)$'s derivative. Try a generalization $a\arctan(bx)$, whose derivative is $\frac{ab}{b^2x^2+1}$. So you want $$\frac{1}{x^2+2}\equiv\frac{ab}{b^2x^2+1}$$ Taking reciprocals: $$x^2+2\equiv\frac{b}{a}x^2+\frac{1}{ab}$$ So you need $b=a$, and $a^2=1/2$.